# Missing Wix 3.8 project template in VS 2013 Express

Tags: wix, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-express, votive

I have installed WIX 3.8 and I still can't find the WIX template in my VS. I don't have a `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\WiX` folder as well. How do I enable Wix in VS 2013 Express?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Visual Studio Express editions don't support third-party packages like WiX's Votive. There's nothing WiX can do to integrate into Express.

Comment: VS Community must now offer that for free, finally :)